# Why do sampled signals repeat in the frequency domain?

Tags: sampling, fourier

I do understand it mathematically, that multiplying a signal with a Kronecker(T) is the same as convolving it with Kronecker(1/T) in the frequency domain, and that makes sense. But is there an intuitive explanation when it comes to this? If I look at my signal, and I see the frequency domain representation, I can see how a number of sines and cosines shown there makes up the original signal. But why does adding even more of the same sines and cosines, but shifted, result in the same signal but sampled?

Comment: They don't, the use of the deltas is stupid and ignores an actual proof of the DTFT. Basically what's going on is a band limited signal can be extended as periodic and the fourier series expansion of it gives coefficients at the sample points, as the fourier coefficient calculation is the same as the inverse of the fourier transform being taken.

Comment: A Sample & Hold is another example of a frequency mixer. It can be used to downconvert to baseband or upconvert DC to AC all by choice of the sampling rate. I used this in the late 70's to use a subcarrier zero crossing of an OCXO PLL'd to 100kHz to sample the same kind of OCXO PLL'd to a sawtooth. So at Liftoff it was nulled to 0V then the result was the same as the rocket range accelerating up to apogee and back with a negative frequency. The difference cycles  was how far away at c/f and with 2 antenna phase diff. the azimuth.  i.e. Doppler S&H mixer

Answer (score 1):

A signal of frequency \$f_{Sig}\$ sampled at \$f_{Sam}\$ is **indistinguishable** from a signal whose frequency is \$n f_{Sam}\pm f_{Sig}\$.

That is why all these other frequencies appear for pure sine waves in the higher Nyquist zones.

When you are presented with only the discrete time DFT, **you cannot infer** which single one (or which mix) of these frequency images is the true continuous wave. This is why analog antialiasing filters are so important. These rule out the higher frequency images and allow you to tell the frequency of the continuous time wave with certainty.